# How to add string item to list?

Tags: android, arrays, list

I am getting an error:

> Girl (String , String ) in Girl cannot applied to (String)

Here is my code:

```
package com.herprogramacion.toolbarapp;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;


public class Girls {

public static final String[] girlsNamesDummy = {
        "Catherine", "Evelyn", "Phyllis", "Beverly", "Michelle",
        "Denise", "Virginia", "Ruth", "Barbara"
};


public static List<Girl> ctrl(int count) {

   List<Girl> items = new ArrayList<>();




    for (int im = 0; im < count; im ++) {

        items.add(new Girl(girlsNamesDummy[im]));

    }

    return new ArrayList<>(items);
}}
```

Here's the girl.class and fully code provided.

```
public class Girl {

    private String name;
    private String yazi;
    private int idDrawable;

    public Girl(String name, String yazi) {
        this.name = name;
        this.idDrawable = getDrawable();
        this.yazi = yazi;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getIdDrawable() {
        return idDrawable;
    }


    private int getDrawable() {

        switch (idDrawable) {
            default:
            case 0:
                return R.drawable.girl1;
            case 1:
                return R.drawable.girl2;
            case 2:
                return R.drawable.girl3;
            case 3:
                return R.drawable.girl4;
            case 4:
                return R.drawable.girl5;
            case 5:
                return R.drawable.girl6;
            case 6:
                return R.drawable.girl7;
            case 7:
                return R.drawable.girl8;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you defined a constructor that takes a single String argument in your Girl class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have posted the Girl class. From what I can say you have a problem with constructors. Where you have a 2 paramater constructor defined (String, String) and you are trying to call a 1 parameter construcctor (String) with this call:

> new Girl(girlsNamesDummy[im])

Comment: I have problem with this line;   items.add(new Girl(girlsNamesDummy[im]));

Comment: @Fatih Yes, it is what I said before. In the Girl class you only have a 2 parameter constructor. So you need a constructor that takes 1 parameter such as: public Girl(String name)